# What significance is the product of two elements within the same dimension?

Tags: linear-algebra, arithmetic, inner-products

Say there are two vectors A (1, 0) and B (2, 0) written as cartesian coordinates (x, y). What *type* of result does multiplying the x elements together produce? By this I mean multiplying 1 and 2 to get result product 2. Does this resulting product 2 have any real world interpretation? If x and y are considered "dimensions", does the resulting product 2 live in x as well or another dimension relative to it? Does it have any units? e.g. if x has units in meters, does the product 1 meter * 2 meter give us 2 meters squared?

Comment: Whether the product of the two first coordinates has any meaning depends on the context in which you encounter the vectors. If you want to think of  $\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}$ as the cartesian product of rings then it is part of the definition of multiplication in that ring. If the numbers come with physical units then the units of the product will be the product of the units.

Comment: If the numbers come with physical units such as meters, what does meters squared even mean? both meters come from the same dimension, so this isn't like an area, produced by product of meters from two orthogonal dimensions.

Comment: Yes. meters $\times$ meters will always yield square meters. If in the context of your problem that makes no sense then you shouldn't be doing that multiplication. That would be the case if the two coordinates of your vector were, say, length and diameter of a wire.

Comment: Ok, agree that it doesn't have utility as a final result. But as an intermediary, isn't the product that we're discussing necessary for computing the dot product of two vectors, which is useful in determining real world values such as angle and length? It sounds like it could be common in math to compute intermediary values that have no meaning in order to attain final values that do. I only am aware of this example so far, but can imagine this happens all the time.